# How to import strophe using requirejs?

Tags: javascript, amd, webpack, strophe

I'm trying to use [strophe.js](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs) with [relay-starter-kit](https://github.com/facebook/relay-starter-kit). I checked out `relay-starter-kit`, added `"strophe": "^1.2.2"` to `package.json` and ran `npm install`.

I can't find how to import strophe without getting errors. If I just try `import Strophe from 'strophe';` I get errors that webpack can't resolve `strophe-polyfill`. I added a resolve alias for that pointing to the main strophe.js file, but that hasn't helped (I just get a console message `Uncaught ReferenceError: Strophe is not defined`).

It looks like strophe has some weird module system (it mentions AMD in github but I thought that meant I could just `require` it, but apparently not). All the examples I've seen import it in an HTML file and clutter the global namespace. I need to use it from within react so I don't think that will work.

How can I import strophe to use in my es6 files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I wasted hours of my life on this, here's the answer:

1. Include strophe in the HTML file with:
2. Edit `server.js` to make webpack expose strophe as a static path with:

   app.use('/node_modules/strophe', express.static('node_modules/strophe'));
3. In the react component, there's no need to import strophe since it's now globally available. Instead just connect with, e.g.:

   var connection = new Strophe.Connection("ws://" + server + ":5280/websocket/");

Comment: Thanks for taking the fall. I'm running into this issue too and hope that there's a cleaner solution involving some magical Webpack configuration to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `import * as XMPP from strophe.js` then call

`var connection = new XMPP.Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE)` to connect server